# histogram misses values in matplotlib, bug?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
bins=np.arange(0,1,0.1)
discrete_pdf=np.power(bins,1.5)
discrete_pdf=discrete_pdf/np.sum(discrete_pdf)
print(bins)
print(discrete_pdf)
print(np.sum(discrete_pdf))
plt.plot(bins,discrete_pdf)
plt.show()
values=np.random.choice(bins, 100000, p=discrete_pdf)
plt.hist(values,10)
plt.show()
```

it's me not able to use `hist` or is a "feature"/bug?

if you force the hist function to male 10*n bins (e.g. 20 or 100) the plot looks reasonable, but it has empty spaces due to finer binning.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are letting matplotlib automatically determine the bins for you by using `plt.hist(values,10)` because the second argument is the number of bins. If we look at the automatic bins generated by matplotlib with a value of `10` for the number of bins they are:

```
[0.1  0.18 0.26 0.34 0.42 0.5  0.58 0.66 0.74 0.82 0.9 ]
```

You can pass in custom bins rather than letting matplotlib automatically decide them. Therefore the solution is to pass in a list (or array) of bins `plotting_bins = np.arange(0,1.1,1)` noticing than an extra bin has been added on the end.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bins=np.arange(0,1,0.1)

discrete_pdf=np.power(bins,1.5)
discrete_pdf=discrete_pdf/np.sum(discrete_pdf)
values=np.random.choice(bins, 100000, p=discrete_pdf)

plotting_bins=np.arange(0,1.1,0.1) # need to add an extra bin when plotting 

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(6,4))

ax1.hist(values, 10)
ax1.set_title("Automatic bins")
ax2.hist(values, bins=plotting_bins)
ax2.set_title("Manual bins")

ax1.set_xlim(0,1)
ax2.set_xlim(0,1)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want to know how the automatic bins are created when you provide an integer for the bins argument we can look at the documentation of [`numpy.histogram()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html#numpy.histogram) (which is what `plt.hist()` uses beind the scenes):

> **bins** : int or sequence of scalars or str, optional
>
> If bins is an int, it defines the number of equal-width bins in the given range

and

> **range** : (float, float), optional
>
> The lower and upper range of the bins. If not provided, range is simply (a.min(), a.max()).

Comment: sure, if I tell it what to do it makes the correct plot, but isn't it a bit buggy to let values disappear with automatic binning? that was my point ...

Comment: The values haven't disappeared. There is no data in the bin `0.42 - 0.5`

Comment: ok, then is a feature of the automatic binning to choose a quite silly one. fair enough.

Comment: Well, not great for your data yes, but I suppose it's OK in some cases, but it shouldn't be relied upon. I've added a bit at the bottom of my answer which explains how the automatic binning is handled